# Position absolute on top of position fixed

Tags: css

I have a header div on my web page that has the property `position: fixed`. Right before this div I have an overlay div which I've given `position: absolute, height: 100%, width: 100%`.

The problem is that the overlay div does not cover the fixed width div (it covers the rest of the content as desired though). How do I make it cover the entire screen?

This has nothing to do with z-index by the way, the overlay div physically begins where the fixed header ends.

```
<body>
   <div id="overlay">
       <div id="dialog">
          <span><span>
          <button id="ok"></button>
       </div>
   </div>

   <div id="header-wrapper">
      <div id="header">
        ....
      </div>
   </div>

    ....
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your overlay should be the one with the fixed: 100% width and height.  Any div's on top of this can be either fixed or absolute positioned.  Beware of using this on webpages used by tablets and phones, it works horribly.

Comment: oh, i miss understood your question, you need to set the z-index of your overlay to something higher than the first fixed element. z-index: 9999;

Comment: Solved it! I had to increase z-index to 20k and add `top: 0`. Thanks anyway chawk.

Comment: okay good, it should be a z-index issue though, if you have 100% width and height of the overlay in question position should not matter it will always take up the full screen.

Comment: Although your answer didn't help my problem as much, I'll accept it in favor for effort. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe I'm wrong but try this solution:

```
#header-wrapper{
    width:100%;
    display: inherit;
}
#overlay{

    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/silentgrave/8uwHB/

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code**

```
#overlay
{ 
position: fixed;
left: 0px; 
top: 0px; 
width: 100%; 
z-index: 1000000000;
}
```

**It will work perfectly**